# C# - Monitor conditional variable (pthread_cond_wait equivalent)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, monitoring

C(++) allows you to do something like this:

```
pthread_cond_wait(condition, &monitor);
```

> These functions atomically release mutex and cause the calling thread to block on the condition variable cond;

```
pthread_cond_broadcast(condition);
```

> The pthread_cond_broadcast() function shall unblock all threads currently blocked on the specified condition variable cond.

Is there anything similar in C# when you want to differentiate monitor waiting?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`Monitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: Monitor class has no override that would allow waiting on the same lock with different conditions.

Comment: What about a [`System.Threading.AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: I don't think that utilizes the [condition variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052(v=vs.85).aspx) internally, introduced in Windows Vista.